# Unable to Create HTTPS Express.JS Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ssl, https

Having lots of trouble trying to get an Express.JS server going that supports HTTPS requests.

Here is the code I've written thus far:

```
import express from 'express';
import fs from 'fs';
import https from 'https';

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

const options = {
  cert: fs.readFileSync('server.crt', 'UTF-8'),
  key: fs.readFileSync('server.key', 'UTF-8'),
};

app.get('/', (request, response) => response.send('Success!'));

https.createServer(options, app).listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

I've created the SSL credentials using OpenSSL on macOS as follows:

```
openssl req -nodes -new -x509 -out server.crt -keyout server.key
```

I've also tried a few other arguments, including increasing key strength to 2048 bits, but nothing has worked. I'm fairly sure that OpenSSL is not the issue here. Requests made to `https://localhost:3000/` fail. I've made the requests through Google Chrome, Node.JS via the `request` module, as well as cURL.

Chrome error: `NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID`

Node.JS error: `Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 172.0.0.1:3000`

cURL error: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.0.0.1 port 3000: Operation timed out`

I've exhausted Google search, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: localhost has IP `127.0.0.1`, not `172.0.0.1`. Also check the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl) to read about problems withs self-signed certificates.

Comment: My bad! Thanks for pointing that out. Still unable to get around the invalid cert error.